# Extract lines from a file in bash

Tags: bash, extract

I have a file like this

I would like to extract the line with the 0 and 1 (all lines in the file) into a seperate file. However, the sequence does not have to start with a 0 but could also start with a 1. However, the line always comes directly after the line (SITE:). Moreover, I would like to extract the line SITTE itself into a seperate file. Could somebody tell me how that is doable in bash?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like :

```
$ egrep -o "^(0|1)+$" test.txt > test2.txt
$ cat test2.txt
0000000000001010000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0011010000000000001010000000000000001000010001000000001001001000011000000000000000101000101010101000
$ grep "^SITE:" test.txt > test3.txt
$ cat test3.txt
SITE:   0    0.000340988542    0.0357651018
SITE:   1    0.000529755514   0.00324293642
SITE:   2    0.000577745511     0.052214098
```

Another solution, using bash :

```
$ while read; do [[ $REPLY =~ ^(0|1)+$ ]] && echo "$REPLY";  done < test.txt > test2.txt
$ cat test2.txt
0000000000001010000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0011010000000000001010000000000000001000010001000000001001001000011000000000000000101000101010101000
```

To remove the characters `0` at beginning of the line :

```
$ egrep "^(0|1)+$" test.txt | sed "s/^0\{1,\}//g" > test2.txt
$ cat test2.txt
1010000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
11010000000000001010000000000000001000010001000000001001001000011000000000000000101000101010101000
```

**UPDATE :** New file format provided in comments :

```
$ egrep "^SITE:" test.txt|egrep -o "(0|1)+$"|sed "s/^0\{1,\}//g" > test2.txt
$ cat test2.txt
100000000000000000000001000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
1010010010000000000111101000010000001001010111111100000000000010010001101010100011101011110011100
10000000000
$ egrep "^SITE:" test.txt|sed "s/[01\ ]\{1,\}$//g" > test3.txt
$ cat test3.txt
SITE:   967         0.189021866    0.0169990123
SITE:   968         0.189149593     0.246619149
SITE:   969         0.189172266  6.84752689e-05
```

Comment: the first solution does not really work for me as test2.txt is empty in my case. When I try the lower solution it is exactly the same...

Comment: @user3419669 Hum, it's work fine for me (as you can see). Can you give copy/paste the extacte commands that you run ?

Comment: I uploaded the real file...I tried it on this file http://speedy.sh/jVC6E/haplo.txt  and it did not work

Comment: @user3419669 There is no `\n` (line feed) between the two lines "SITES:..." and "00001..."  (unlike your example). Isn't it ?

Comment: @user3419669 : See the part "UPDATE" of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover, I would like to extract the line SITTE itself into a seperate file.

That’s the easy part:

```
grep '^SITE:' infile > outfile.site
```

Extracting the line *after* that is slightly harder:

```
grep --after-context=1 '^SITE:' infile \
    | grep '^[01]*$' \
    > outfile.nr
```

`--after-context` (or `-A`) specifies how many lines *after* the matching line to print as well. We then use the second `grep` to print only that line, and not the actually matching line (nor the delimiter which `grep` puts between each matching entry when specifying an `after-context`).

Alternatively, you could use the following to match the numeric lines:

```
grep '^[01]*$' infile > outfile.nr
```

That’s much easier, but it will find **all** lines consisting solely of 0s and 1s, regardless of whether they come after a line which starts with `SITE:`.

Comment: hey when I use your lower line of code i get an output which looks likeSITE: 1  0.000529755514   0.00324293642 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (but I wanted only the 0/1 sequence)

Comment: Try just `awk '/^SITE:/ { s++; next } s--'  infile`

Comment: @user3419669 I cannot reproduce this (in other words, it works for me …). But you can make it more robust by applying the change I’m posting now.

Comment: @tripleee That won’t work because `grep` puts delimiter lines between the entries (but unfortunately it does so inconsistently across platforms, hence my edited code version).

Comment: There is no `grep`. Just run Awk on the input file.

Comment: @tripleee Duh, I misread your comment. That’s actually a very nice and clean alternative, post it as an answer / EDIT wait, it doesn’t actually work for me … trying to figure out why not.

Comment: Hellol...I tried this several times no and I dont see why it doesnt work. However, could you have a brief look at the original file? (http://speedy.sh/jVC6E/haplo.txt) I really dont know what is wrong

Comment: @user3419669 that doesn’t work, the site wants me to download an exe which acts as a downloader. I’m not on Windows (and I wouldn’t use that anyway). Put the file on gist.github.com, pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: @tripleee: It would have to be `awk '/^SITE:/ { s++; next } s { print; s=0 }'  infile` - in your solution, `s` gets decremented too often.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `awk` solution that matches all lines starting with `SITE:` and outputs the respective **next** line:

```
awk '/^SITE:/ { if (getline) print }'  infile > outfile
```

Simply omit the `{ ... }` block part to extract all lines starting with `SITE:` **themselves** to a separate file:

```
awk '/^SITE:/' infile > outfile
```

---

If you wanted to **combine** both operations:

`outfile1` and `outfile2` are the names of the 2 output files, passed to `awk` as variables `f1` and `f2`:

```
awk -v f1=outfile1 -v f2=outfile2 \
  '/^SITE:/ { print > f1; if (getline) print > f2 }'  infile
```